# Why is my code using monadic lists from the List package so slow?

Tags: list, haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Last week user Masse asked a [question about recursively listing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881835/how-to-list-directories-faster) in a directory in Haskell. My first thought was to try using monadic lists from the [`List` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/List) to avoid building the entire list in memory before the printing can start. I implemented this as follows:

```
module Main where

import Prelude hiding (filter) 
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (join)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.ListT (ListT)
import Data.List.Class (cons, execute, filter, fromList, mapL)
import System (getArgs)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesDirectoryExist)
import System.FilePath ((</>))

main = execute . mapL putStrLn . listFiles =<< head <$> getArgs

listFiles :: FilePath -> ListT IO FilePath
listFiles path = liftIO (doesDirectoryExist path) >>= listIfDir
  where
    valid "."  = False
    valid ".." = False
    valid _ = True
    listIfDir False = return path
    listIfDir True
      =  cons path
      $  join
      $  listFiles
     <$> (path </>)
     <$> (filter valid =<< fromList <$> liftIO (getDirectoryContents path))
```

This works beautifully in that it starts printing immediately and uses very little memory. Unfortunately it's also dozens of times slower than a comparable `FilePath -> IO [FilePath]` version.

What am I doing wrong? I've never used the `List` package's `ListT` outside of toy examples like this, so I don't know what kind of performance to expect, but 30 seconds (vs. a fraction of a second) to process a directory with ~40,000 files seems much too slow.

Comment: We could use a `Data.ByteString.getDirectoryContents :: ByteString -> [ByteString]`.  When you consider 40,000 files at 10+ characters each, that's 400,000 characters.  A [Char] in Haskell takes what?  Ballpark 12 bytes (x86) or 24 (x86-64).  So those 400,000 characters are 8MB or more spread throughout a linked list.  Now that I've said all this, hopefully you will respond with "I've benchmarked getDirectoryContents and that isn't the issue".

Comment: @TomMD: I'm primarily interested in the comparison with `FilePath -> IO [FilePath]` versions that use `getDirectoryContents` in exactly the same way (Masse's original implementation, for example). So I don't think this is the problem, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profiling shows that `join` (together with `doesDirectoryExists`) accounts for most of the time in your code. Lets see how its definition unfolds:

```
  join x
=> (definition of join in Control.Monad)
  x >>= id
=> (definition of >>= in Control.Monad.ListT)
  foldrL' mappend mempty (fmap id x)
=> (fmap id = id)
  foldrL' mappend mempty x
```

If in the root directory of the search there are `k` subdirectories and their contents are already computed in the lists: `d1, d2, ... dk`, then after applying `join` you'll get (roughly): `(...(([] ++ d1) ++ d2) ... ++ dk)`. Since `x ++ y` takes time `O(length x)` the whole thing will take time `O(d1 + (d1 + d2) + ... + (d1 + ... dk-1))`. If we assume that the number of files is `n` and they are evenly distributed between `d1 ... dk` then the time to compute `join` would be `O(n*k)` and that is only for the first level of `listFiles`.

This, I think, is the main performance problem with your solution.

Comment: The `concat` in Masse's original implementation (which is much faster) seems to be doing exactly the same thing, but I'll look into this in more detail.

Comment: Concat gets turned by fusion rules into the following, but I'm not clear if it is necessarily faster, and I'm not up for benchmarking at the moment: `  "concat" forall xs. concat xs = build (\c n -> foldr (\x y -> foldr c y x) n xs)`

Comment: To both comments. ListT defines its own list type, so there is some added indirection in all operations on it.

Comment: It's defined like this: data ListItem l a =
  Nil |
  Cons { headL :: a, tailL :: l a }

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious, how well does the same program written to use [logict](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/logict) work for you?  `LogicT` is semantically the same as `ListT`, but implemented in continuation-passing style so that it shouldn't have the `concat`-related type of problems you seem to be running into.

```
import Prelude hiding (filter)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Logic
import System (getArgs)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesDirectoryExist)
import System.FilePath ((</>))

main = sequence_ =<< observeAllT . fmap putStrLn . listFiles =<< head <$> getArgs

cons :: MonadPlus m => a -> m a -> m a
cons x xs = return x `mplus` xs

fromList :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
fromList = foldr cons mzero

filter :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a
filter f xs = do
  x <- xs
  guard $ f x
  return x

listFiles :: FilePath -> LogicT IO FilePath
listFiles path = liftIO (doesDirectoryExist path) >>= listIfDir
  where
    valid "."  = False
    valid ".." = False
    valid _ = True
    listIfDir False = return path
    listIfDir True
      =  cons path
      $  join
      $  listFiles
     <$> (path </>)
     <$> (filter valid =<< fromList <$> liftIO (getDirectoryContents path))
```

Answer (score 1):

Running it on a large directory reveals a memory leak. I suspect this has to do with the strictness of getDirectoryContents, but there might be more going on. Simple profiling didn't turn up much, I'd add some extra cost centers and go from there...